# NSJSONSeralization.dataWithJSONObject crashing

Tags: json, xcode, swift, ios8

I have trouble with the NSJSONSeralization.dataWithJSONObject.

This will make my application crash:

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {

    cachedMessage = messageField.text
    messageField.text = ""

    let messageData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(cachedMessage, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)

...

}
```

I hope you can somehow help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will give you an error like : **Invalid top-level type in JSON write**

If you are trying to create a JSON object then it should be either from Array or Dictionary. **Because An object that you want convert in to JSON Must be a Top Level object.**

> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.

Try in this way :

```
    var demoArray : NSArray! // (Use it if you want to send data as an Array)
    var demoDic : NSDictionary! // (Use it if you want to send data as an Dictionary (Key - Value Pair))

    var cachedMessage : String! 
    cachedMessage = "Sample" // Here your String From textfield

    demoArray = [cachedMessage] // Array with your string object
    demoDic = ["Your Key":cachedMessage] // Dic with your string object.
```

You can provide your desired key instead of Your Key

This is how you can create Data from array and Dictionary.

```
    let msgDataOfArray = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(demoArray, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error:nil)
    let msgDataOfDic = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(demoDic, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)
```

If you want to see how your data will look after JSONSerialization process then you can see like below way

```
    var DataToStringForArray = NSString(data: msgDataOfArray!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var DataToStringForDic = NSString(data: msgDataOfDic!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    println("Data To String OF Array : \(DataToStringForArray)")
    println("Data To String OF Dic : \(DataToStringForDic)")
```